# Xquery to ingest temporal document under temporal collection- throwing error in MarkLogic query console

Tags: marklogic, bi-temporal

I am executing below xquery to ingest a unitemporal file in a temporal collection which lies under a MarkLogic database- Schemas.
I am getting below error

Xquery which I am running

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace temporal = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/temporal"
      at "/MarkLogic/temporal.xqy";
let $root :=
<tempdoc>
   <content>v1-content here</content>
</tempdoc>
let $options :=  
<options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">
    <metadata>
       <map:map xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map">
         <map:entry key="systemStart">
           <map:value>2014-04-03T11:00:00</map:value>
         </map:entry>
         <map:entry key="systemEnd">
           <map:value>2014-04-03T16:00:00</map:value>
         </map:entry> 
       </map:map>
    </metadata> 
</options> 
return
```

Error:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting Function30_ or Percent_
Stack Trace
At line 21 column 0:
In xdmp:eval("xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;;&#10;import module namespace t...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>1754687030342455867</database>...</options>)

 </metadata>
 </options>
 return
```

Comment: you are missing the statement to return. You have let 2 variables and then have `return` with nothing after it. `return temporal:document-insert(...`

Comment: Thanks, added the function after return and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved now, I was not returning the document insert function which was rightly pointed by @MadsHansen. Its solved now.